# Whats does var counter = array.length, temp, index mean?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning javascript and I have troulbe understanding this chunk of code:

```
var counter = array.length, temp, index;
while(counter > 0)
{
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
    counter--;
    temp = array[counter];
}
```

In particular, the `var counter = array.length, temp, index` line. What happens when I define `counter` as `array.length`, `temp`, and `index`? Thanks!

Comment: It's equal to `var counter = array.length; var temp; var index;`

Comment: That doesn't help. What are temp and index?

Comment: Yea, it's just a shorthand way of creating variables. 

So like:

    var poop = [1, 2 , 3 , 4];

    var one = poop.length, temp = whatever here (in your case they are starting out empty or null), index;

Comment: Temp is assigned each iteration through your while loop.  Index isn't really used in this loop, but it may be used outside later in the code.  They are null after creation.

Comment: So i'm basically creating two variables at once?

Comment: @John Green: btw, they are `undefined` after declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line isn't defining `counter` as `array.length`, `temp`, and `index`.  `counter` is defined only as `array.length`.  `temp` and `index` are declared but not defined as any particular values.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I was wondering why I would be setting 2 variables equal to counter.

Answer (score 0):

This line creates three separate variables.

It is equivalent to:

```
var counter = array.length
var temp;
var index;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code sample, the first line defines variables outside of the while loop. This way, over all iterations within the while loop, and after completion of the loop, the content of the variables remains accessible.

The first line could also be written as follows:

```
var counter = array.length;
var temp;
var index;
```